# SRP. Save to repository when edit. Internally or externally?

Tags: object-oriented, solid, single-responsibility

For example:

```
class Data {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public void someEditMethod() {}
}

class DataRepository {
    public void save(Data data) {
        // save to DB
    }
}
```

I need save Data when editing.

How better?

internally:

```
....
public void someEditMethod() {
    repo.save(this);
}
....
```

or externally:

```
....
DataRepository repo = new DataRepository(dbConnection);
Data data = new Data(repo);
data.someEditMethod();
....
```

Externally is uncomfortably, and I do not want to impose class customers knowledge about the repository.

Comment: Internally. ....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the 2nd and 3rd code snippets. The "internally" one looks like it's just showing us the implementation of the method called in the "externally" one; they don't look like alternative approaches so much as two obviously necessary parts of any approach that involves a DataRepository class. What makes the former "internal" and the latter "external", and why is the latter "uncomfortable"?

Comment: i'd like to ask whether to include repository in the domain entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing repository and active record together. If you want to use repository in the true sense ([such as M. Fowler suggests](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)), the external approach is what you want to go for, but external in a different way than your proposed design.

With repository the process should look something like this:

```
DataRepository repo = new DataRepository(dbConnection);
Data data = repo.GetData();
data.someEditMethod();
repo.Save(data);
```

If you want to use the internal approach, then the design is called active record - an entity which knows about its persistence (and although it is frown upon as an anti-pattern it can sometimes be better than use the repository approach).

The active record is not very popular in enterprise world, because the entities which usually know about their persistence also include business logic and thus mix two reponsibilities.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use Observer pattern for listen changes and save to the repository.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко You really should **not** be mixing all the design patterns just because you just learned about them. Beautiful code is code easy to read. Not code abusing all the posibilities of a language. Be careful not to overdesign the code.

Comment: I want save to the repository when data will change. How can i do it without observer pattern?